# Class not working jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

So I more than one dynamicly generated elements with the same class name that I am trying to check input for in jQuery. Instead of it letting me click on both, it is just letting me click the first element generated.

Ex: I click on item_1 and it returns the item_1 id, but when I click on item_2 it doesn't return anyting.

HTML

```
    <div id="item_1" class="resp"></div>
    <div id="item_2" class="resp"></div>
```

JS - Jquery

```
    $(".resp").on("click",() =>{
      var id = $(".resp").attr("id");
      console.log('attempting toggle' + id);
    });
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Firstly, you have to use normal function instead of arrow function (to avoid missing the context). Secondly - use `this` keyword to refer to the actually clicked element.

```js
$(".resp").on("click", function() {
  console.log('attempting toggle ' + this.id);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="item_1" class="resp">A</div>
<div id="item_2" class="resp">B</div>
```

Comment: if the `divs` are added dynamically should event delegation be used? i.e. `$(document).on('click', ".resp", function(){});`? [jQuery event delegation doc](https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/)

Answer (score 2):

This is because `.attr('id')` returns the value of the `id` attribute of the first matched element in the set.

Instead, use an old school function for the handler so the `this` value is equal to the clicked div, then get its `id`:

```js
$(".resp").on("click", function() {
  var id = $(this).attr('id');
  console.log('attempting toggle ' + id);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="item_1" class="resp">First</div>
<div id="item_2" class="resp">Second</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

What you're doing here is referencing the classname to obtain the id. This gathers the id of the first classname, which isn't what you desire. What you need to do is use the `this` keyword to correctly obtain the id.

After removing the arrow function and changing the internal code a bit, it should look like this:

```
$(".resp").on("click", function() {
  var id = this.id;
  console.log('attempting toggle: ' + id);
});
```

Also make sure you've correctly installed JQuery. Pick up your JQuery embed code from [here](http://code.jquery.com).
Also remember to include your JQuery code **before** your JavaScript code.